# Extracting classes and their properties from PHP files

Tags: php, windows, oop, parsing

I want to extract all declared classes and their methods and attributes from a PHP file (with an external tool) to post process this information in another application. I could try to write a parser myself but due to PHP's mostly type-less syntax it would be hard to achieve this, so I would like to use the PHP command line interpreter or some other command line tool.

Is it possible to parse a PHP file **without** executing it and just get the defined classes and their methods and attributes?

I tried the -e parameter (*"Generate extended information for debugger/profiler"*) but it doesn't seem to return anything.

The -f parameter parses **and** executes the file (I don't want PHP to execute it).

The -l parameter only checks the syntax and tells if something is wrong or not.

Comment: Have you looked at PHPDocumentor?

Comment: PHPDoc is written in PHP, which is not what I want (at least not as a PHP script). As far as I can see PHPDoc also requires additional extensions and PEAR and maybe something else. I need a mostly independent tool, API or source code which serves my own application. Unfortunately PHPDoc is too overloaded to distribute it with my application.

Comment: I think you misread PHPDocumentor.... no PEAR required, and no extensions that you're unlikely to have either.... but if you want something that can analyse PHP Classes that isn't written in PHP, then I think you'll have to write it yourself in your choice of language

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that such an old post doesn't really have an answer.

```
spl_autoload_register
```

This will allow you to register classes without having to load them into memory and they can then be called with namespacing.

```
ReflectionClass
```

Will let you demonstrate the properties of the class